# Capturing screenshot of a webpage in tiff format via phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, tiff

I want to capture webpage screenshot.I am planning to use phantomjs for it.But phantomjs only supports **png &jpg**.I want the webpage screenshot to be in **tiff**.Is it possible to do so?

Comment: How about ImageMagick?

Comment: @stark I will try & will inform u  whether its working /not

Comment: @stark I downloaded it.But I cant run it via command prompt.In there site they said I can convert the image to different format via **convert **.But it is not working